# Asp.Net Core React+Redux tutorials or what are React, React+Redux and ReactJs.net?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, react-redux

I got burned pretty badly following an AngularJS tutorial with Asp.net before finding out AngularJS is the first iteration of Angular and we're up to version 4 which is completely different to the first one but kept the name anyway.

So I want to try something else, namely React+Redux on the merits that it must be better than React because it also includes Redux (whatever that is).

I'm actually struggling to find tutorials for React+Redux and was hopeful someone could point me in the right direction, there is so much information out there I'm kind of confused and don't want to repeat my AngularJS mistake.

Comment: Change is a fact of life in software development.  There's no guarantee that you'll have the kind of stability you want in any other library.

Comment: I really loved the part "because it also includes Redux (whatever that is)." haha. Explains my feelings time to time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To Understand React**

React Fundamentals:  https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/react-fundamentals (Just understand the concepts. Do not follow follow Author's Quiz Example.)

For React setup refer: https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-setup-i

**To Understand the ASP.Net Core fundamentals**

Watch: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-core-fundamentals (Only first five sections, upto Models  in the MVC Framework)

Watch: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/asp-dot-net-core-restful-api-building (only first five sections. Skip example of asp.net core api)

Follow below link for asp.net core and api basic with environment setup in VS code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started

**To Understand Redux.**
Learn Redux (Skip react videos) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w-oQ-i1XB8&index=15&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b

Read Best Practices: https://getstream.io/blog/react-redux-best-practices-gotchas/

Practice Basic understanding of Redux with example: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/

This is the guide which we follow in our office to get the understanding about all this concept.

You can learn also by creating a TODo app with using all these concepts together.

Let me know if you need more help on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is good boilerplate for React ASP.NET core, Redux, React, TypeScript, Router and Webpack server side rendering. Everything what you need to start dev single page app ... just download this and generate solution for Visual Studio and that is it :-)

When we started in our company with React and Redux and .net core we have used it and I have to say that is good way how to start.

[JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices)

Good point to start is also check this grate video tutorials for Redux/React

[Getting Started with Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)

[Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux)