# Asp.Net Core JavaScriptServices - React

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, react-redux, single-page-application, asp.net-core-2.0

I have worked with react in asp.net MVC (Before .net core released) using ReactJs.net. Right now I am working with .net core. I want to use React with asp.net mvc core. I know that Microsoft has provided Javascriptservices to use for single page application.

Unfortunately I am not getting any good tutorial for Asp.net core JavascriptServices with react. There are few available but its with Angular only.

I came across this [Asp.Net Core React+Redux tutorials or what are React, React+Redux and ReactJs.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859832/asp-net-core-reactredux-tutorials-or-what-are-react-reactredux-and-reactjs-ne) 
It is good source but its individual course on .net core, react,redux etc.

This is also not giving in depth view - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

I am looking for tutorial on how to use Asp.net Core Javascriptservices with React template for real time web application. I am not sure how to start with it.

Anybody can provide good reference for that please? or any suggestion?

Comment: Nobody has any idea?

Comment: Could you find good resources on this one? Btw, do you work with Javascriptservices or ReactJS?